# Redefine author-year to match Harvard style Anglia Ruskin flavour

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I am customizing [LaTeX
templates](https://gitlab.com/template-tugasakhir-latex/template-proposal-latex)
for me and my friends to use. Because our college didn't provide one. After
spending 3 days I can get it working and match the docx template from
my college, except it lacks in producing the same bibliography style.

My college use '[Harvard Anglia Ruskin's
flavor](https://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm)' which
seem [they didn't provide the `.bst` file](https://github.com/sdstrowes/Glasgow-Thesis-Template/issues/3#issuecomment-159756164).

I am aware that customizing `authoryear` style has been discussed
here. But taking those answer one by one seems not a clear solution.

Searching 'Anglia' in this forum also didn't get me any result. Maybe
this flavor not so popular.

---

I can get the 'in-text referencing' to work using:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, % author year style
%\usepackage[style=agsm, % author year style
firstinits=true, % abbrev fist name
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first} % put last name fist at
                            % bibliography list
```

But I am catching to make the 'the reference list' style work.

The style look like this:

> Author, Initials., Year. Title of article. *Full Title of Journal*, Volume number (Issue/Part number), Page number(s).

> Boughton, J.M., 2002. The Bretton Woods proposal: a brief look. Political Science Quarterly, 42(6), p.564.

> Cox, C., 2002. What health care assistants know about clean hands. Nursing Times, Spring Issue, pp.647-85.

And my current style still like this:
*not actual citation*

> Rumbaugh, J., Jacobson, I., & Booch, G. 2017. “Exploring Plagiarism into Perspectives of Indonesian Academics and Students”. In: Journal of Education and Learning Vol. 11 (3), pp. 262-272.

I need to remove quote in title, make journal title italic and remove
the 'in'. e.g

> Author, Initials., Year. Title of article. *Full Title of Journal*, Volume number (Issue/Part number), Page number(s).

I have successfully removed the parentheses from the year using this code

```
\usepackage{xpatch,filecontents} % remove parens from reference list
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
```

But I don't know how to mimic the whole style above and keep
consistency.

Comment: Can you show us a full minimal example of what you have so far for the bibliography: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. The example document need not include all other modifications of your template, just those for the bibliography. Do also include some example citation entries, that will make it easier to get started for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first attempt at addressing the most pertinent requirements of the Anglia Ruskin Harvard system as laid out in the full guide from https://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm

The base style is `ext-authoryear-comp` of my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle. This makes it slightly easier to apply some of the necessary modifications, namely "editor name before title for `@in...` works", "remove parentheses around year" and many small punctuation changes. `biblatex-ext` and the rest of the code below assume a modern `biblatex` version.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-comp, giveninits, uniquename=init, maxbibnames=999,
  urldate=long,
  innamebeforetitle, articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

% 1.2
\DeclareDelimFormat*{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% 2.5
\DeclareDelimFormat{andothersdelim}{\addcomma\space}

% 2.7
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}

% 2.8
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother

% ignore 2.10 for the time being

% 4.1
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldAlias{biblistlabeldate}{biblabeldate}

% 4.3
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}

% 4.4
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

% as for the year of the chapterv vs year of the book in 4.4
% I have never seen such a distinction and in general I imagine
% it would be quite hard to find out the year of a chapter
% in a collection work since only the year of the collection is given
% I imagine that in practice you would almost always end up douplicating
% the year.

% 4.8 & 5.11
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom   = {available at},
  urlseen   = {accessed},
  bathesis  = {BA},
  mathesis  = {MA},
  phdthesis = {PhD},
}
\newcommand*{\mkbiburlangle}[1]{<#1>}
% or {<#1>}
% or {\ensuremath{\langle}#1\ensuremath{\rangle}}
% or {guilsinglleft#1\guilsingleright}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space \mkbiburlangle{\url{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibcpstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% 4.9
\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

% 4.12 :-(
% note that I used the new preferred resolver https://doi.org/
% instead of http://dx.doi.org/
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}

\cite{companion}

\cite{yoon}

\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\cite{westfahl:space,westfahl:frontier}

\cite{markey,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output from the MWE above, a bit too long for a proper transcription, I'm afraid]

Comment: Wow, you write so fast. I just on the way of updating my question. here is the [draft](https://gist.github.com/azzamsa/0eed13087c0e6eac36eb6ec56bc914c0).  So now I need to copy 1.2 - 4.12  to my tex file ?
Thank you

Comment: @azzamsa You need everything from `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` up to `\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}`. Just replace everything `biblatex`-related that you have so far with the new code.

Comment: Oh no. I live in developing country :). I need to upgrade to texlive 2018 that need 1.5 GB. then upgrading to the latest biblatex-ext. Need hours, cause I use mobile phone tethering right now. || I tried to run your code and it works great, I will ask again if any problem happened. So far I tried `@article` and `@book` it works great compared to Angila guide. Thank you so much Sir. You help many people here. Thank you.. hope your kindness will be rewarded. Hope this part of code will be incorporated to your package :). Have great day.