# Redefine author-year to match Harvard Anglia flavour follow-up questions

Tags: harvard-style

First of all, a big thank you, @azzamsa and @moewe, for discussing this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446633/redefine-author-year-to-match-harvard-anglia-flavour) first and providing a solution! I need to use ARH style as well, and it's driving me crazy. I use the suggested [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446633/redefine-author-year-to-match-harvard-anglia-flavour) from Moewe, but I still have some problems with it:

1. Somehow, it doesn't show the accessed date for my URLs (in your
   example, it's the reference (Markey, 2005). Specifically, I am using
   the following BibTeX entry:

   ```
   @misc{delvaux.1990,
   author = {Delvaux, Tom},
   year = {1990},
   title = {{In the Arctic}},
   url = {www.gmail.ubi.com},
   urldate = {02/28/2021}
   }
   ```

and it shows:

> Delvaux Tom, 1990.In the Arctic. Available at:
> <www.gmail.ubi.com> [Accessed ].

So the date is not shown. I have already tried the following versions:

```
    urldate = {02.28.2021}
    urldate = {28/02/2021}
    urldate = {28 February 2021}
```

These give me the same result of not displaying the date accessed. **Does anyone have an idea of what I can do about it?**

2. I am missing the format of the electronic resources ( [pdf], [e-journal], [online], and [e-book]). For example, the output should look like this:

> Goodall, A.H., 2006. Should top universities be led by top researchers and are they?: A citations analysis. *Journal of Documentation*, [e-journal] 62(3), pp.388 - 411. http://dx.doi.org/10.1108/00220410610666529

> NHS Evidence, 2003. National Library of Guidelines. [online] Available at: <http://www.library.nhs.uk/guidelinesFinder> [Accessed 10 October 2009].

> Bank of England, 2008. *Inflation Report.* [pdf] Bank of England. Available at: <http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/publications/inflationreport/ir08nov.pdf> [Accessed 20 April 2009].

**Any idea on how to add the format?**

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Date fields in `biblatex` must be filled in ISO 8601 `YYYY-MM-DD` format regardless of the expected output, so `urldate = {02/28/2021},` and all other input shown in the question are wrong. You want `urldate = {2021-02-28},` (there should have been a Biber warning about those incorrect input formats).

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the date :D

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you, Moewe, for the tip with the date format!** I don't think that I would have guessed it.

Regarding my second question, I found the solution myself:
for BibTeX types `@misc`, `@manual`, and `@patent`it is possible to add a field type called `type = {}` in which I can specify the format of the resource.

```
@misc{delvaux.1990,
author = {Delvaux, Tom},
year = {1990},
title = {{In the Arctic}},
url = {www.gmail.ubi.com},
urldate = {2021-02-28},
type = {[online]}
}
```

gives the output :

> Delvaux, T., 1990. *In the Arctic.* [online]. Available at:
> <www.gmail.ubi.com> [Accessed Feb. 28,2021].

Note that I added a comma after the urldate!