# What Latex bibliography system to choose?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I am working on my thesis, and I am struggling to choose between BibTeX and Biber.

I am using TexStudio + Miktex + Mendeley on Mac OS.

My university requires us to use the Anglia-Ruskin Harvard system. This means, that I need standard authoryear + names of the works in italic + accessed dates for online content.

See example below:
[image]

From what I understood now, Bibtex do not offer Date Accessed functionality. Biblatex is a bit confusing.

For the record, I am completely new to this side of informatics, so I am very confused what is the difference between the apps, packages etc.

It would help me a lot if I could choose one system to use and focus on learning it.

Merry Christmas!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446633/35864

Comment: Generally speaking `biblatex` is said to be easier to customise than BibTeX (it can be modified on the LaTeX side with LaTeX commands and does not use BibTeX's slightly arcane reverse Polish notation). It also offers more features out of the box. The advantage of BibTeX is that there are many styles readily available for it (no Anglia Ruskin style, though, as far as I can see). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for more details.