# Reformatting bibliography output

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently using `biblatex-bath` and need to change one word and the position of another in the outputted Bibliography as below.

This is the `.bib` reference

```
@article{anyone,
title = {Test document for bibliography},
volume = {20},
url = {http://web.ebscohost.com},
pages = {331--353},
number = {3},
journaltitle = {Bulletin for Research},
shortjournal = {Bulletin for Research},
author = {{Anyone}, Bob},
urldate = {2019-02-22},
date = {2010},
keywords = {Peer reviewed},
```

It currently looks like this

[image]

I need [Online] in every instance to appear before the Available from text and also 'from' changing to 'at', so it looks like the below.

[image]

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, british, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\bibliography{zotero.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{anyone}
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can mark up code by indenting it with four spaces or by clicking the `{}` button. Please don't include HTML markup (`<br>`) in the source code. Please also include the relevant entry of your `.bib` file (`anyone`) in your question.

Comment: The braces around `Anyone` in `author = {{Anyone}, Bob},` are superfluous and can be removed, `author = {Anyone, Bob},` is much better. No `biblatex` style that I know of applies sentence casing to names (and it would be a *very* bad idea to do that), so there is no point in adding those braces. Indeed, they could even lead to issues once https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414685/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-bath` uses a macro called `isonline` that is inserted into all kinds of macros to typeset the "[Online]" bit. So the first step is to redefine that macro to print nothing. The second step is to print the "[Online]" in the desired location. Here it seemed easiest to do that in the `url`  field format.

The "available at" can be changed by redefining the bibstring `urlfrom`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, british, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom = {available at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \bibsentence\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}%
  \addspace
  \bibsentence\bibstring{urlfrom}%
  \addcolon\space
  \url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{ctan}
\printbibliography[title=\bibname]
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN, (2006). Ctan: the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. [Online] Available at: http://www.ctan.org [Accessed 1 October 2006].]

As mentioned in [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476416/35864), it might be viable to start from a standard style instead of a custom style like `biblatex-bath` if you expect more changes.

Comment: thanks again for your help, it is really appreciated.